# Bad Marshall data when Installing private python lib in zc.buildout

Tags: python, reportlab, buildout

I'm getting bad marshal data error when installing a dependency for one of my projects. If we install using standard virtualenv, it works fine without errors.

Here is a portion of my zc.buildout (currently the part that causes the error is commented out):

```
[buildout]
versions = versions
extensions = mr.developer
unzip = true
include-site-packages = false

# FIXME
# Attempting to install from here via buildout raises a bad marshal data error
# I should note that this errors does _not_ occur when we install in a
# clean virtual environment. It only happens in buildout.
# find-links = https://<myuser>:<mypass>@www.reportlab.com/pypi/simple/rlextra/

# Temporary solution, we included the package manually and will add it as
# a develop egg, then in the "django" part further down, we need to
# include the package in the extra-paths.
develop = ${buildout:directory}/libs/rlextra-3.1.9
```

Traceback:

```
Getting distribution for 'rlextra==3.1.9'.
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
rlextra.thirdparty.xlrd.xlsx: module references __file__
rlextra.utils.buildutils: module references __file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1973, in main

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1954, in with_ei_usage

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1977, in <lambda>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 360, in run

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 584, in easy_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 634, in install_item

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 829, in install_eggs

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1109, in build_and_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1095, in run_setup

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 33, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 81, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 35, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 78, in <module>
  File "setup.py", line 73, in main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 227, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 266, in zip_safe
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 402, in analyze_egg
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 433, in scan_module
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
An error occured when trying to install rlextra 3.1.9. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue, and how it can be resolved. We are currently managing this by manually downloading and including the package (as you can see in the buildout config), which is not ideal.

Comment: And what is the full traceback error? 'bad marshall data' sounds like you have `.pyc` files in the library that are for the wrong Python version or otherwise corrupted.

Comment: Added the traceback. That said I didn't think that the python version might be the cause. I'll check that

Comment: The zip-safe scan is failing; a `.pyc` file is attempted to be loaded, which uses `marshall` to store the code object and constant values, and loading that `.pyc` file is what is failing. Since pip doesn't support eggs, you'd not see this problem with that. It is otherwise not clear why one of your .pyc files in your egg fails to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be related to the way we used to obfuscate files which were considered proprietary. Until 3 months ago, the modules that we wished to hide were transmitted as raw pyc files with a suffix indicating their python version eg rml2pdf_27.pyc, rml2pdf_33.pyc etc etc.

Now we transmit a single python file that contains the embedded compiled code as data so it should not now be visible to packagers. That change took place after 3.1.9 was created.

Comment: Thank you! Upgrading to 3.1.38 resolved this issue :)